# Unable to parse XML present in string property of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml, svg

Javascript JSON.parse() is unable to parse string that contains XML or SVG.

I have tried remove attributes from example and it worked like a charm, notice it only fails when XML contains attributes.

Following JSON string are failed to passed using JSON.parse();

```
{ "id": 1, "mahtml": "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" display=\"block\"><msup><mi>a</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mn>2</mn><mrow><mo>(</mo><mi>a</mi><mo>&#x00D7;</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>" }

{ "id": 1, "svg": "<svg height=\"100\" width=\"100\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"red\" /></svg>" }
```

Following JSON string are parsed successfully using JSON.parse();

```
{ "id": 1, "mahtml": "<math><msup><mi>a</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mn>2</mn><mrow><mo>(</mo><mi>a</mi><mo>&#x00D7;</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>" }

{ "id": 1, "svg": "<svg/><circle/></svg>" }
```

Comment: use XMLSerializer to convert svg to string representation then convert to JSON with JSON.stringify

Comment: I don't see any error message. And can you provide runnable code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing the JSON is copied manually. `\"` has to be `\\"` for  the `\` to be escaped :

```js
var json = '{ "id": 1, "mahtml": "<math xmlns=\\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\\" display=\\"block\\"><msup><mi>a</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mn>2</mn><mrow><mo>(</mo><mi>a</mi><mo>&#x00D7;</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math>" }'

console.log( JSON.parse(json) )
```